# Filter store records - Distinct

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am fetching some records, and using the filter property as shown below;

```
store = Ext.getStore('PEOPLE');
store.on('load', function() {
    store.filter({
        filterFn: function(f) {
            return f.get('Name') == "SAM"; 
        }
    });
});
store .load();
```

The above code, will filter **all** Names that has the name `SAM`. But, what i want it to **ONLY** return 1 name (just only SAM (**Once**)).

For example, in databases we use the keyword **DISTINCT** to get just 1 record (if there are multiples). How can i do this in my scenario ?

Comment: you can set maxResult to 1 for this while fetching record.

Comment: Where should i add this field ?

Comment: How do i apply it in my code ?

Comment: show me your database query code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this perhaps what you're looking for?

```
store = Ext.getStore('PEOPLE');
store.on('load', function() {
    store.filter({
        filterFn: function(f) {
            return f.get('Name') == "SAM"; 
        }
    });
    if(store.getTotalCount() > 1)
        store.remove(store.getRange(1));
});
store.load();
```